# ser.readline() returns Null characters (^@)

Tags: gps, debian, pyserial, beagleboneblack, nmea

I'm reading time and date from a GPS by RS-232 in a BeagleBone Black.
I have 2 BeagleBones Black Rev C, using Putty as terminal:

**First one with Debian Stretch:**

```
root@beaglebone:~# uname -r
4.16.0-rc2-bone3
root@beaglebone:~# cat /etc/debian_version
9.3
```

**Second one with Debian Wheezy:**

```
root@beaglebone:~# uname -r
3.8.13-bone79
root@beaglebone:~# cat /etc/debian_version
7.11
```

Both have the pyserial lib version 3.4

**The first one, Debian Strech reads the messages perfectly:**

timestamp_gps = ser.readline()

**Output:**

```
$GPZDA,113340.00,08,03,2018,,*62
timestamp formatted = 2018-03-08 11:33:40.00
```

**The second one, Debian Wheezy don't read the comman and other characters:**

```
timestamp_gps = ser.readline()
```

**Output:**

```
$GPZDA355.0000306
timestamp formatted = 0-03-0 3:55:.00
```

**Timestamp that was supposed to be readed:**

> 2018-03-08 13:55:47

**So, the message that was supposed to be readed:**

> $GPZDA,13:55:47.00,08,03,2018,,*43

**If i save the output in a txt file and edit the file with *nano* i get this:**

> $GPZDA^@^@355^@^@.00^@0^@^@03^@^@0^@^@^@^@^@6^@^@
>
> ^@0^@^@-03-0^@ ^@3:55:^@^@.00

Any help, would be aprecciated

Comment: Are the settings the same for both of them? Baud rate, stop bits, data bits, parity, etc.

Comment: Yes @MikaS, the software are exactly the same.